Is it possible to use Mendeley to produce chapter notes without a citation?
Is it possible to use Mendeley to insert sequential text chapter notes without a citation?
For example:
Chapter text
Lorem ipsum dolor [1] sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod [2] tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore [3] magna aliqua.
Chapter Endnotes

Dummy Citation One. (2024). Dummy citation report. Retrieved from http://www.dummywebsite.com
Text without a citation
Dummy Citation Two (2024). Dummy citation report. Retrieved from http://www.dummywebsite.com


I don't undestand the question. What is [2]?

Do you simply mean you can add your own explanatory text in a footnote? Or is there some restriction in Mendeley that forbids footnotes for other than citation?
